# Definition of the ../../dir/index.html URL Path syntax

Tags: https, url

I've searched the net for an example of the ../../ URL path that is in some existing code that I'm troubleshooting, and have not been succesful.  I need to know how to find the absolute path to where this would be pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

`..` means the parent directory of the one that you are currently in. In the context of some code it will mean the parent directory of the one in which the code is running. Depending on what exactly the code is this could be a number of different places.

`../../dir/index.html` means that `index.html` is two directories 'up' and then inside the `dir` directory.